# Why is the previous checkbox still showing after I have returned a completely new div?

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a filter for a clothing website. The filter will have different colors to choose from based on what is available for each product category. I currently have pants and shirts set up.

Shirts Filter

[image]

Pants Filter

[image]

The problem is that if I check something on the shirts filter, when I go to the pants page those boxes are checked as well, where the previously checked shirt checkboxes used to be.

Shirts Filter Checked

[image]

Pants Filter Checked (not supposed to be)

[image]

Can someone please explain why this is happening? I understand that react usually works by only updating what is new but this should be a completely new div element unrelated to the other filter checkboxes.

Also, when I uncheck the boxes on the pants page I can see that it is still connected to the previous color from the shirts page and not the new color. Then when I check it again it connects to the correct color from the pants page.

Here is the code I use to return it:

```
<div className="filter-type">
   <div className="Color">
      <p>Color</p>
      {props.cfa.map((color, idx) => {
          return <ColorFilterSlots key={idx} color={color} function={AddRemoveClass}/>})}
   </div>
</div>
```

```
const ColorFilterSlots = (props) => {
   let color = String(props.color);
   let colorUp = color[0].toUpperCase() + color.slice(1).toLowerCase();
   return (
      <div className="input-row">
          <input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={false} id={color} name={color} onChange= 
              {props.function("color", color)} />
          <label htmlFor={color}>{colorUp}</label>
      </div>)
}

export default ColorFilterSlots
```

Comment: No one has an answer?